# linking GA4 project to bigquery - streaming vs daily

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I recently linked my GA4 property to bigquery to better look at the analytics data. That was initially on daily, so every day the data was exported from Google Analytics to Bigquery. However, I decided that streaming is necessary so I switched from daily to streaming in the BigQuery Linking section of GA4's admin tab. However, that streaming data is not showing up after a few hours. I'm wondering if anyone has done this with similar problems. Do I need to recreate an entire bigquery project?

Comment: @Brain Guan You don't see a different table in BigQuery other than tables for daily data?

Comment: Does the latency period affect your tables? For the past 3 days, data can change, I am getting three insert jobs; and I want to run a cloud function after the last insert job.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your configuration options for GA to BigQuery, you will see a message under the streaming option.

> This option will take effect after the next date boundary (tomorrow) for this property.

This property = the "Data exported continuously" option (streaming)

You will probably see your data tomorrow.